# is it allowed to choose name Rasool Muhammad

Tags: naming, names

Assalam o Alaikum
one of my friend name is Rasool Muhammad. is this name is correct and what is the meaning of this name

Comment: It means Messenger of Muhammad. I don’t see anything wrong in that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is about naming https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/is-is-specific-name-a-suitable-name-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Rasool in Arabic means messenger.
Muhammad is the name of our Prophet ().

In Arabic Rasool Muhammad makes only sense if you spoke of somebody who has been sent out by -a person called- Muhammad to deliver a message, as Rasool would be an adjective. In that case it would mean "Messenger of Muhammad".

Each word of this possible name makes sense and doesn't go against any naming [conventions in Islam](https://islamqa.info/en/7180) even if it might sound strange as a name for an Arabic speaker. But this is not a reason to say it is incorrect or not allowed.

Comment: You answered the question even though you put it on hold as off-topic?

Comment: @Armaan yes I was looking for an overall answer, but couldn't find it, and my explanation was too long for a comment.

Comment: Very nicely answered. However, there's an important & major factor one  needs to consider while choosing a name. It is social/society environment you live in.
People with less knowledge or non-Muslims (both comes in less knowledge category),may take miss-lead by similar sort of names. Also, there are people,use to call with wrong nick names,will create problem in the society. Some people will feel anger on this in any context or being in state of mind. So, better to be careful and open while doing any consideration. Islam educates people to avoid any kind of possible Fitna/Sharr.